# How to save images stored in the public folder in Laravel project to the database

Tags: laravel, medium-editor

How to save images stored in the public folder in Laravel project to the database using the medium editor plugins

Comment: Find a file manage plugin for medium text editor. And ntegrate it with Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Upload to public folder. Set `image` column value to this path.

**File Path**

/path/to/project/public/uploads/image.jpg

**Database Column Value**

uploads/image.jpg